# jQuery foo.html("<span>bar</span>") not changing foo[0], so what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

Using jQuery, in Firebug, if the following is done one by one:

```
foo = $('<div>foo</div>')

foo[0]  // => <div>

foo.html('<span>bar</span>')

foo.html()  // => "<span>bar</span>"

foo[0]  // => <div>

$('body').prepend(foo)  // => shows bar at top of page
```

it is strange that `foo.html()` shows the `span`, but `foo[0]` shows the `div`... why is the inconsistency?  It seems that `foo` became a jQuery wrapper for a `span` element.  Shouldn't `foo[0]` show the `span` also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`html()` writes/reads the innerHtml property of the `<div>` element; it doesn't replace the element. What you actually have now is `<div><span>bar</span></div>`. So no, this isn't particularly strange behavior. :)

Answer (score 1):

The index accessor on a jQuery object accesses the element in the jQuery sequence. In your example, you've created a jQuery sequence with just one element - the `div`. You can set the contents of that `div` to be any kind of complex tree, but it's still just one element. `html('')` sets the inner contents of the node, but the outer node remains unchanged.

Comment: ah, ok, html() or innerHTML is to replace everything under that node, as in divOne.innerHTML = "<a ...>click me</a>".  The `div` is still there.  It is just that everything underneath the `div` node is changed.  Sometimes easy to forget, especially after a beer.

Comment: @Jian Lin: keep drinking and you may be able to reach the Ballmer peak: http://xkcd.com/323/ :)